# Conditional expectation of $X$ given $X+Y$

Tags: probability

$X$ and $Y$ are two random independent variables, they have the same distribution and have finite expected value. Find $ \mathbb{E} [X|X+Y] $

My attempt:

$$ \mathbb{E}[X|X+Y] + \mathbb{E}[Y|X+Y] = X + Y $$
Whats more $$ \mathbb{E}[X|X+Y] = \mathbb{E}[Y|X+Y] $$ 
because $X$ and $Y$ have the same distribution.

Hence:
$$ \mathbb{E}[X|X+Y] = \frac{1}{2}(X+Y) $$

**Edit:**

From comments below I conclude that this is a sufficient solution.

Comment: If $X$ and $Y$ have the same distribution, this should hold by definition; they are the same function over $A$.

Comment: Don't you have your answer at the point you say "Hence: $ \mathbb{E}[X|X+Y] = \frac{1}{2}(X+Y) $" ?